# how to update the UITableView data while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have displayed data in the `UITableView`.The listing is for add cart items in cart list.

[image]

According to this picture can see the following details:-

1. price
2. Name of product
3. Stepper to add the quantity
4. Total Amount

So for this Firstly I added the product in the `UITableView`. Then stepper action to increases or decreases the quantity, I given the code according .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "cell"
        var cell: ChartCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ChartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell
        }


     cell.setEventData(carts: chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

    cell.cartadd = { [weak self] in

        if let i = self?.tableView.indexPath(for: $0) {

            let productid = self?.chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
            print(productid?.cartid)

            self?.chartViewModel.search(idsearch:productid?.cartid)
            print(self?.chartViewModel.searchindex(objectatindex: 0))
            cell.setcartData(cartsadd: (self?.chartViewModel.searchindex(objectatindex:0))!)
            print(cell.quantity)

            self?.chartViewModel.totalPriceInCart()
            let theIntegerValue1 :[Int] =  (self?.chartViewModel.totalvalue)!
            let result = "\(theIntegerValue1[0])"
            print(result)
            let theStringValue1 :String = String(describing: result)
            print(theStringValue1)

            self?.totalresult.text = theStringValue1
            print(i)

        }
    }
```

the viewmodel:-

```
class ChartViewModel: NSObject {


    var datasourceModel:ChartDataSourceModel

     var totalvalue:[Int] = []
    var insertedArray:CartModel? 

    var filteredListArray:Array<CartModel>? = []
    var productArray:CartModel?

     var finalListArray:Array<CartModel>? = []

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: ChartDataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

    }
    func search(idsearch :String?) {

        filteredListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter{($0.cartid?.range(of: idsearch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)}
        print(filteredListArray)


    }


    func searchindex(objectatindex index: Int) ->  CartModel {

        return self.filteredListArray![index]

    }



    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> CartModel{

             return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]


    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

            return datasourceModel.dataListArray!.count


    }

    func delete(atIndex indexPath: IndexPath) {

        datasourceModel.dataListArray!.remove(at: indexPath.row)
         print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

    }

    func totalPriceInCart() {




        var totalPrice: Int = 0
        for product in datasourceModel.dataListArray! {

            totalPrice += product.cartsumint!

            print(totalPrice)


        }
        self.totalvalue = [totalPrice]

   }



    func insert(atIndex indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(productArray)
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
        datasourceModel.dataListArray!.insert(productArray!, at: indexPath.row)
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
        self.datasourceModel.dataListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
        self.finalListArray =   self.datasourceModel.dataListArray
    }

      func add()  {

            datasourceModel.dataListArray?.append(insertedArray!)
            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
            print(insertedArray?.offerAddName)
            print(insertedArray?.offerprice)

            self.datasourceModel.dataListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray

            print(insertedArray?.cartsum)

    }

 }
```

The above code is to add the quantity. And this code is given in `UITableView` `cellForRowAt` delegate.
But the problem is:-

-As i adding the quantity of product ,the price also changes And will display in the `UITableView`. But while scrolling the `UITableView` the data will show as before.That means :-

initial suppose:- product name : car, price: 300, quantity: 1

This will show at `UITableView`. When I added quantity: 2, So price: 600 this will show in the `UITableView`.
But the problem is while scrolling the `UITableView` it become as price: 300, quantity: 1. 
So how to update the `UITableView`. what should do

The UITableviewCell:-

```
 func setEventData(carts:QM_CartModel)
    {



        self.name.text = carts.cartname

        self.price.text = carts.carttotalprice


        self.itemQuantityStepper.value = 1

        setItemQuantity(quantity)



        print(self.price.text)


        let value = carts.cartsum



        let x: Int? = Int(value!)
        print(x)


        let add = x!
        print(add)


        let theIntegerValue1 :Int =  add
        let theStringValue1 :String = String(theIntegerValue1)
        // self.price.text = theStringValue1

        self.price.text = "QR \(theStringValue1)"
        print(self.price.text)


    }


    func setcartData(cartsadd:QM_CartModel)
    {

        let theIntegerValue :Int =  self.quantity
        let theStringValue :String = String(theIntegerValue)
        cartsadd.cartquantity  = theStringValue
        print(cartsadd.cartquantity)
        print(cartsadd.cartsum)

        let value = cartsadd.cartsum
        let qty = cartsadd.cartquantity

        let x: Int? = Int(value!)
        print(x)
        let y: Int? = Int(qty!)
        print(y)


        let add = x! * y!
        print(add)


        let theIntegerValue1 :Int =  add
        let theStringValue1 :String = String(theIntegerValue1)
       // self.price.text = theStringValue1


        self.price.text = "QR \(theStringValue1)"
        print(self.price.text)


        cartsadd.cartsumint = theIntegerValue1
      //  print(cartsadd.cartsum)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your data(updated) in your model class.Because while scrolling tableview dequeuereusablecell again call and it will get data from model that's why you always get old data.

Comment: please check ,i have updated some more code which i have done.So according to that how to update?

Comment: @brucecraigb As I read your question earlier you assign new value to your controller..what you need to do is your have to access your particular array row(you have to send your currentIndexpath to your every IBAction of controller) and after adding new value particular array you just need to reload your UITableView

Answer (score 1):

```
class TableViewCellData {

    var data: Any?
}
```

-

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellData: TableViewCellData?
    {
        didSet {
            // change data in cell from TableViewCellData
        }
    }

    var cartadd: (() -> Void)?
}
```

-

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataSource: [TableViewCellData] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.cellData = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.cartadd = {
            cell.cellData?.data = "" // set data to TableViewCellData
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```